# node-postgres not parsing queries correctly

Tags: express, pg, node-postgres

I am trying to count the number of documents in a table that satisfy a condition.

My code in node:-

```
const [washingCount, washedCount, dirtyCount] = await Promise.all([
        pool.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clothes WHERE status = 'washing'"),
        pool.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clothes WHERE status = 'washed'"),
        pool.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clothes WHERE status = 'dirty'")
    ])
```

But I am getting the error saying:

> error: column "count" does not exist

And when I copy the same query over to PostgreSQL CLI, those output the desired results.

[image]

For full code refer:- https://github.com/js313/clothio/blob/master/index.js

Error stack trace:-
[image]

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not reproducible. Please paste the entire contents of the script where you're trying to do the query. May be the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: @RahulSharma https://github.com/js313/clothio/blob/master/index.js, please refer to this link for the entire code. Endpoint throwing error is at line 69.

Comment: Again. Not able to reproduce. Try `curl -XGET http://localhost:300/clothes/count` after starting the app on your local machine and see what happens.

Comment: @RahulSharma still the same error, even tried reinstalling 'pg' module. I added the full error stack trace if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't use `group by`?

```
select status, count(*) from clothes group by status
```

**Edit**

tested with a simple script like this and worked

```js
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
});

async function main() {
  const result1 = await pool.query("SELECT now()");
  console.log(result1);

  const result = await pool.query(
    "SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM clothes group by status"
  );

  console.log(result.rows);
}

main()
  .then()
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

---

**Edit 2**

Found the issue in your repo code.

Route registration order matters, so you have this route.

`app.get("/clothes/:cloth_id", async (req, res) => {`

before the count one, so express is getting into this route and never reaching the `count` one.

To solve the issue move the `/clothes/count` route before the `clothes/clothe_id` one and that should solve the issue

Comment: I am new to relational databases, feel stupid now as I know what GROUP BY does. Anyways, this has the same issue, working in the CLI but throwing the same error of "column count does not exist" when using node-postgres.

Comment: added an edit, I tested with that script and worked as expected

Comment: No still the same error, I added the whole error message to the question, if it helps.

Comment: ok, used your repo to check and the issue has nothing to do with node-postgres and  it is related to route ordering in express :D, check the new update

Comment: I am so stupid! That is express 101, and the unfortunate part being the id named 'count', never thought to check the routes. On the bright side, I now know a practical example of when to use GROUP BY. Thank you :)